# iPhone:Orientation Issue

Tags: iphone

I have facing an issue that I want to change orientation according to user interface.
What I mean iss when user change the app in to LandscapeLeft, LandscapeRight or Potrait mode, I want to change the orientation according to this change.

Please give me any link or any idea to develop this functionality.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3):

In the method:

```
- (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation
```

add the following code:

```
return YES;
```

Then your view controller will start rotating. Similarly add the above code in all the view controllers.
After that you have to handle all the controls are placement accordingly.

Comment: Use autoresize masks in your NIBs.

Comment: if you want a totally different layout, you need to set frame of each subView manually. You may want to "google UIViewAutoResizing".